# How to avoid installing the same software on google cloud instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using the compute engine of the google cloud platform to do computations.

I am using Ubuntu as the OS and every time I create a new instance, I have to install the software I need from scratch, including the `build-essential`.

I am pretty sure there is a way to specify the software I would like to have in my VM but couldn´t figure out a straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [GCE custom images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images) to create VM images with pre-installed software that you need.

Alternatively, you can consider using [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) in which you can install software during VM startup. But in contrast to custom images it will increase VM startup time, because startup script will be running during VM startup.